# What did the Datapoint 3300 character font look like?

Tags: terminal, font

We know from the Datapoint 3300 [Maintenance](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/datapoint/3300/70116_3300termMaint_Dec76.pdf) manual the characters were formed on a 5x7 grid, and on page 2-55 we have an "A".  But is it known what the rest of the characters looked like?  According to the [Instructions](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/datapoint/3300/Datapoint_3300_Instructions.pdf) manual, the 3300 had old ASCII style ↑ and ← instead of ^ and _, which doesn't match the TI datasheets.

EDIT: I'm adding a picture of the character generator ROM from the schematics.
[image]

EDIT: This is from the 1971 TI datasheet.
[image]

Comment: Page 2-51 of the maintenance manual seems to indicate that the character generator ROM was an off-the-shelf part and varied depending on whether the terminal was an -801, -802, -803, -804, or -805 model.  For example, the -805 model used an MOS MCS1005 chip, while the earlier models used TI chips (at least I assume that's what the TMS prefix means).  If you can find datasheets for any of them, they might include bitmaps.  I haven't been able to find any datasheets myself, though.

Comment: @Ken That comment is worth turning into an answer, with a link to the manual.

Comment: @cjs, there's a link in the question.

Comment: @KenGober, I have also searched for those datasheets, to no avail so far.

Comment: I've been limiting myself to comments on this because it's still possible that the ROM was a custom part -- it was not uncommmon for manufacturers of such parts to allow a customer to provide their own custom bitmaps.  The data sheets would clarify whether custom bitmaps were an option and if so what the part numbers would be, if different versions were denoted by, say, different suffixes on the same base part number.

Comment: @KenGober - it *could* have been custom, but that would have been an expense for Datapoint. Old character generators of the time had very similar bitmaps - see [TMS 2400 JC](https://archive.org/details/bitsavers_tidataBookrcuits14_11987466/page/n129/mode/2up/search/character+generator) (1971), [Fairchild 3258](http://www.citylan.it/wiki/images/5/58/3258.pdf) (197x), [MOS MK2300P](http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/components/mostek/_dataBooks/1974_Mostek_Integrated_Circuit_Guide.pdf) (≤ 1974; p.25) - so there's a good chance it was generic

Comment: Thank you @scruss for those links.  I added some of the TMS characters to my question in case it jogs anyone's memory.

Comment: The TMS 4103 on page 106 here: http://bitsavers.org/components/ti/_dataBooks/1975_TI_The_Semiconductor_Memory_Data_Book.pdf has the same pin names as the 3300 schematics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer may not contain a good enough image( although the last link may also be useful since it seems to use identical font ), here is part of an image on the following catalog -

[image]

That catalog can be downloaded at -
https://www.computerhistory.org/collections/catalog/102646159

https://archive.computerhistory.org/resources/text/Computer_Terminal_Corporation/ComputerTerminalCorporation.Datapoint3300.1969.102646159.pdf

The following videos uploaded by one person may help -
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=juuM6jvu2a0
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i5r9jkoIPVQ
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aqg8L6G077w

Also, paste the name of the catalog detailed above, into google-search -
"computerterminalcorporation.datapoint3300.1969.102646159"
 and some sites for interesting reading result.

Here's a restored one, but they did not upload a photo of the screen on.
https://www.vintagecomputer.net/browse_thread.cfm?id=455

http://www.vintagecomputer.net/ctc/3300/
**____________________________________**
The following is part of a screen image for the Datapoint 1100 which seems to have identical font-
[image]
The link for the image is -
http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/datapoint/1100/Dataform_1100_Brochure_1974.pdf

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful!  I'm already in contact with Bill Degnan.